# Where is this blank space coming from?

Tags: html, layout, xhtml

I have a webpage that contains a picture inside a table cell. But, in the table cell there is also an additional 5px on the bottom.

I simplified the code to the max:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Random page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid black">
<img style="border: 1px solid red" src="picture.png" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The result, in Firefox 25 and Internet Explorer 10:

[image: Result]

As you can notice there is blank space in the bottom.

I know this could be caused by whitespaces, so I removed all of them between tags. No effect.

The weirdest part is, if I remove the `DOCTYPE` specification, or replace it with HTML or XHTML Transitional (Strict does *not* work), it starts to work.

Is this a weird quirk of HTML/XHTML Strict or what? Can it be worked around and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:** By default, the bottom of an image lines up with the baseline of the surrounding text.  The gap you're seeing is for the decenders of any descending letters (q, y, p, g) that surround the image.  The fact that you have no surrounding text makes no difference - space is still reserved for it.

**Solution:** You need to align the bottom of the image with the bottom of the line, rather than the baseline:

```
img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RichieHindle/g8Lwg/).

Answer (score 2):

set your img to

```
display:block;
```

that should solve it

Comment: There is someone more clever than I who can explain it properly but it's something about treating the img in the same way as text. I assume text has line spacing below but converting it to a block object removes such spacing

Comment: All right, this solves the problem (and I'm probably going to use it because a block of easier to handle on my situation), but I'm still accepting Richie's answer for the explanation.

Comment: Actually, the way it works is that when the img becomes display:block, no line box is formed for the img to be displayed in. If there's no line box, then there's no strut, so no space needs to be allocated for character descenders. Note that is completely different to RichieHindle's solution, (or vertical-align:top) which works by disconnecting the alignment of the strut from the alignment of the img so both the strut and the img can use the full height of the minimal line box. A third approach is to set the container's font-size to 0, which makes the strut have 0 height.

Comment: solid proof to show that 1 problem has many possible solutions

Answer (score -1):

Put the closing cell tag immediately after the image, like:

```
<img style="border: 1px solid red" src="picture.png" /></td>
```

Comment: As I said, I removed all the newlines in the document without effect.