# Spacing between image in HTML table

Tags: html, image, html-table, border, space

I am wasting a lot of time doing a simple thing:

I want to show an image and I want to show the same image under the previous one.
I've put the two image in a table, but I have a strange space under the image.

This is the simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<LINK href="style_new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<?php

echo "<table class=\"top\">";
echo "<tbody>";

echo "<tr><td class=\"t_top\"><img src=\"try.png\" vspace=\"0px\"/></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td class=\"t_top\"><img src=\"try.png\" vspace=\"0px\"/></td></tr>";
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

and relative style sheet:

```
table.top
{
border-spacing:0px;
border:0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-spacing: 0px;

}

img.top
{
border-spacing:0px;
border:0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

td.t_top
{ 
border-spacing:0px;
border:0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}

tr.t_top
{ 
border-spacing:0px;
border:0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

My image have an height 58px. I've tried to check on various browser and spaces are still there. I'have some pixel of space down the image and up the `<td>` border (that I've put to check), then I have `<td>` and `<tr>` object that are 62px but the img object is 58px

Can I remove this spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to do this as discussed in an already answered question.

Set the img to

```
display:block;
```

or set

```
lineheight to 0px;
```

or set

```
vertical alignment to top.
```

I don't know best way to link to existing question. I havent paid much attention. Explaination can be given if asked.

I found it: [Where is this blank space coming from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010299/where-is-this-blank-space-coming-from/23010409#23010409)

Answer (score -1):

Please add below css in your stylesheet.

**set float property to left**

Thanks,
Hasmukh